# How to download an image in socket connection and remove the unwanted bytes

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-io

I need to download an image throught socket connection. Currently I have a byte array which contains a .jpg file also some other unwanted bytes (ffd8). I need to remove these unwanted bytes from my byte array. I tried to download the file without removing the bytes then I got image in corrupted format.  So I would like to know how can I remove the unwanted bytes from my bytearray.

Here in my code:

```
  while (!status) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // or 4096, or more
                        int bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        int availableBytes = input.available();

                        str2 = str2.append(bytesRead);
                        ImageDataArray = concat(ImageDataArray, buffer);
                        countPackets = countPackets + buffer.length;
                        if (input.available() != 0) {
                            System.out.println("String:" + str1.toString());
                        } else break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("--------------------out of while ------------------");
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), "/SteelmanPro/1020/images/image" +filename1);
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                }
                write(ImageDataArray, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/SteelmanPro/1020/images/image" +filename1);
```

concat() method:

```
 public  byte[] concat(byte[]...arrays)
{
    // Determine the length of the result array
    int totalLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    {
        totalLength += arrays[i].length;
    }

    // create the result array
    byte[] result = new byte[totalLength];

    // copy the source arrays into the result array
    int currentIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    {
        System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, currentIndex, arrays[i].length);
        currentIndex += arrays[i].length;
    }

    return result;
}
```

write method:

```
 void write(byte[] aInput, String aOutputFileName) {

    Log.e("dfd", "Writing binary file...");
    try {
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aOutputFileName));
            output.write(aInput);
        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e("dfd", "File not found.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("dfd", "" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed a dozen or more pointless blank lines. Don't waste vertical space, especially on the Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which contains a .jpg file also some other unwanted bytes (ffd8)
>   I tried to download the file without removing the bytes then I got image in corrupted format

As removing `FFD8` made you end up with corrupted and you still try to do that, what needs to happen to make you stop thinking that "unwanted" bytes are actually "very wanted"? (pun intended)

In fact `FF D8 FF` is JPEG's [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) and is part of the JPEG file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comment: actually I didnt remove that. I knew that it indicates the start of a JPEG file. I need to store  bytes after this magic number

Comment: Wha for you need to store corrupted JPG file? You're "saving" 2 bytes literally per file - I am really curious about use case here.

Comment: So I dont need to remove the magic number from my byte array?

Comment: No. If you want to store JPG files you need it all, incl. magic number.

Comment: ok. till now, I am not removing magic number but getting currepted image

Comment: Using the same code I could save video files and able to play it.

Comment: Can you download the image using i.e. browser? If so do that, and compare with what your code downloads. Check size and if equal, check content.

Comment: No, I am using desktop and here establishes a socket connection through local wifi. My actual requirement is, I have an external camera device which is connected to our mobile phone using wifi, this external camera has storage capacity and which stores images and video, once I establish a socket connection to the hardware device I could download the images and video. But downloaded images in currepted format with approximately correct file size. (eg : If an image has 258 kb I am getting file size of 260 kb)

Comment: approx correct size? it's IT. It's either correct or not. dude, 258KB vs 260KB is damn 2048 bytes difference. And you most likely reads this from i.e. Windows properties dialog at wrong place. Eh...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142070/discussion-between-liya-and-marcin-orlowski).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is littered with errors.

```
while (!status) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // or 4096, or more
```

This array should be allocated outside the loop.

```
    int bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    int availableBytes = input.available();
```

Calling `available()` is usually pointless, and this is no exception, not least because you aren't using `availableBytes` anywhere.

```
     str2 = str2.append(bytesRead);
```

If this is an image you should not be storing it in a `String`. `String` is not a container for binary data.

```
        ImageDataArray = concat(ImageDataArray, buffer);
```

As you haven't posted `ImageDataArray` it is impossible to know what this means.

```
        countPackets = countPackets + buffer.length;
```

Wrong. It should be `countPackets + bytesRead`. You cannot assume that `read()` fills the buffer. That's why it returns a value.

```
        if (input.available() != 0) {
```

Another misuse of `available()`. It is not a test for end of stream, or end of message.

```
            System.out.println("String:" + str1.toString());
        } else break;
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------out of while ------------------");
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), "/SteelmanPro/1020/images/image" +filename1);
     if (!file.exists()) {
         file.createNewFile();
    }
```

As you are about to create a `new FileOutputStream(...)` with the same name, this block is not only redundant but wasteful.

```
}
write(ImageDataArray, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/SteelmanPro/1020/images/image" +filename1);
```

As you haven't posted this `write()` method it is impossible to comment on it.

concat() method:

```
public  byte[] concat(byte[]...arrays)
```

The signature is already wrong. You don't know that any of these arrays is filled. See above.

```
{
    // Determine the length of the result array
    int totalLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    {
        totalLength += arrays[i].length;
    }

    // create the result array
    byte[] result = new byte[totalLength];

    // copy the source arrays into the result array
    int currentIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    {
        System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, currentIndex, arrays[i].length);
        currentIndex += arrays[i].length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You don't need the entire method. You should write data to the file *as you received it.* Instead of wasting memory and adding latency.

Don't write code like this.

Comment: 'byte[] ImageDataArray= new byte[0];' . I had posted the write() method , please check it .